# Determine if a string has all unique characters

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

This is from cracking the Coding Interview Book

The Questions Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. What if 
you can not use additional data structures?

I am wondering what is happening in the if statement below? can anyone explain it to me ?

I have left my understanding of the code in the comments.Please correct me if i am wrong

```
public class Uniquechar2 {

    public static boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
         // Create a new boolean array of 256 characters to account for basic a cii and extended ascii characters
         boolean[] charSet = new boolean[256];

         //iterate through the array
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

             // Assign the value of current value of the iterator i to int variable val.So if we are looping through "hello"  at i = 0 the int value of 'h' will be assigned to val.Is that correct?

             int val = str.charAt(i);

             // Continuing from the example of loping throughout the string "hello" the if statement will see if 'h' is in charSet and since it will be there it will return false /is that what is happening?

             if (charSet[val]) {
                 return false;
             }
             // Is this the else statement? true will be assigned to charSet[h] in this case       
             charSet[val] = true;
         }
         // I dont understand why we are returning true at the end ?
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: I indented the code. Once indented, it's much easier to understand. Next time, do that yourself.

Comment: There are more than 256 different characters.

Comment: @Alan do you mean there are more than 256 ASCII characters?

Comment: There are 128 ASCII characters. But a Java `String` is not constrained to just that set.

Comment: You should replace your first code comment with a check that the input can be handled by your algorithm and throws an exception if it can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
     // Create a new boolean array of 256 characters to account for basic ascii and extended ascii characters
     boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];

     // Iterate through the string we are testing
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

         // Get the numerical (ascii) value of the character in the `str` at position `i`.
         int val = str.charAt(i);

         // If char_set[val] has been set, that means that this character was already present in the string. (so in string 'hello' this would be true for the second 'l')
         if (char_set[val]) {
             return false;
         }
         // If the character hasn't been encountered yet (otherwise we would have returned false above), then mark this particular character as present in the string
         char_set[val] = true;
     }
     // If the function hasn't returned false after going through the entire string that means that each character is unique - thus returning true
     return true;
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome explanation!

Answer (score 4):

> Is this the else statement

No, otherwise there would be an `else` in the code. But in this case, `else` is unnecessary since, if `char_set[val]` is true, the execution of the method stops immediately, due to the `return false;` instruction.

> I dont understand why we are returning true at the end ?

Because since no duplicate has been found, the method must return true to indicate that the string is composed of unique characters. If a duplicate had been found, the method would have returned already in

```
if (char_set[val]) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are we assigning true to charSet[val] in the statement charSet[val] = true? In the string "hello" when i iterates through h using the statement  if (charSet[val]) {
                 return false;
             } ,charSet[val] will be true since 'h' in present in the charSet array so how are we checking for duplication here .Can you demonstrate with example like that of "hello" how we are checking for duplication here

Comment: `if (charSet[23])` doesn't test if there is an index 23 in the charSet array. It tests if the value at index 23 of the charSet array is true. And by default, all elements of a boolean array are false.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use regex, which requires only one line of code:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    return str.matches("((.)(?!.*?\\2))*");
}
```

Breaking down the regex:

- `(.)` captures every character
- `(?!.*?\\2)` is a negative look ahead for a back reference to the captured group

Together, these mean "a character that does not reappear after itself"

- `(...)*` around the above means 0-n of them

Altogether, it means "comprised of characters that do do reappear later in the string", ie unique characters.

Comment: Why wrap the entire thing in a capture group?

Comment: how to  interpret this "!str.matches("((.)(?!.*?\\2))*")"

Comment: @ark a group around the whole expression is needed  so I can apply `*` to it. It didn't need to be a captured group, but regex are hard to read anyway and adding `?:` makes more regex noise

Comment: Clever ... but not an efficient solution.  (And certainly not readable, unless you have a senior regex wizard's badge.)

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution without any extra data structure:

```
str.chars().distinct().count() == (int)str.length();
```